# Easy/basic page numbering and limiting the size of returned data in the .NET Core 2.2 Web API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I need to add easy page numbering and limiting the size of returned data in Web API to such a controller. The whole project is on GitHub as if someone would like to see more.

https://github.com/lukaszFD/IPI-PAN_WEB_API

```
public class Documentation
{
        private readonly DocumentationContext _doc;
        public Documentation()
        {
            _doc = new DocumentationContext();
        }
        public async Task<List<GrTables>> DBDocumentation()
        {
            List<GrTables> list = await Task.Run(() => _doc.GrTables.ToList()).ConfigureAwait(true);
            return list;
        }
}
```

```
public class GrTablesController : ControllerBase
{
        private readonly ILogger<GrTablesController> _logger;

        public GrTablesController(ILogger<GrTablesController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [HttpGet("Documentation/All")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<GrTables>>> GetGlobalRespositoryDocumentation()
        {
            var data = await new Documentation().DBDocumentation();

            if (data == null)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("No data found for GetGlobalRespositoryDocumentation/Documentation/All");
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(data);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using pagination on Your EF queries. Something like this:

```
  public async Task<List<GrTables>> GetPaginatedResult(int pageSize, int pageNumber)

  {
            var query = _doc.Set<GrTables>().AsQueryable();
            return await query.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
  }
```

I also like to return the paginated data with info that helps to process and request more paginated data.

```
 public class PageMetadata
 {
        public int TotalRecordCount { get; set; }

        public string NextPageLink { get; set; }

        public string PreviousPageLink { get; set; }

        public string FirstPageLink { get; set; }

        public string LastPageLink { get; set; }

        public int ActualPage { get; set; }

        public int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }

        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
 }

 public class PagedResponse<TResponseModel>
 {
        public IEnumerable<TResponseModel> Records { get;  set; }

        public PageMetadata Metadata { get;  set; }
 }
```

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPagedServiceData(
            [FromQuery] int pageNumber,
            [FromQuery] int pageSize)
{
            var result  = await new Documentation().GetPaginatedResult(pageNumber, pageSize);
            return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be like that?  return await query.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageNumber ).ToListAsync();

Comment: I don't need these two classes (PageMetadata,PagedResponse) in this solution, do I? Just an implementation in EF ?

Comment: No, you should take the page size quantity. And yes, (PageMetadata,PagedResponse) are not needed, it's just an example.